# Multiple VBOs and IBOs How to Handle

Tags: opengl

Actually, I have a lot of models that are produced by cpu.(around 100K and one of them around 100 triangle) and all model has its vbo and ibo. If I try to draw each model with glDrawElements() it is quite slow. also if I try to draw combine all vbos and ibos if a model is deleted I need to update vbo also almost all ibo because of removed points change index order and then I need the buffer all of these again it is slow. Also I am not sure about instancing performance and picking I need to know which triangle belongs to which model.Is there any way to buffer and than one draw function draw all individual model with its own vbo and index?

Comment: Seeing a bit of code would help. How do you update your VBO data, how does your drawing code look like. Stuff like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a base vertex per mesh and pass it to the [`glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawElementsBaseVertex) call. This will still require a call per mesh which can be solved with [`glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex) with which you can combine them all into a single draw call.